# What does Revelation 3:14 say about Jesus? What kind of witness is the speaker of Revelation 3:14? What does this say about the time of creation?

Tags: revelation

The American Standard Version of Revelation 3:14 says,

And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: These things saith the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of the creation of God.

This verse reinforces the perception of Jesus' (the Word) prehuman existence but answers refuting that perception are encouraged.

Is Jesus the firstborn from the dead and of the new regime only or is he the firstborn of all creation as well as the firstborn from the dead?

Is this verse harmonious with Colossians 1:15 and John 1:1-3?

Comment: _Does this verse say that in the beginning Jesus existed "in the mind of God, that's why he was foreknown"?_ No, it doesn't. Those words are yours, not Paul's.

Comment: @Nijel J. The words Jesus existed "in the mind of  God, that's why he was foreknown" were actually user48152's comment to der ubermensch answer to his question about Jesus being the word before he was born. I asked this question to test whether the bible reinforces that specific comment.

Comment: That's why it is never a good idea to utter the words of an error when one is campaigning against it. Better to state truth in such a way that the error never gains a platform.

Comment: You reference Revelation 3:14, but the paragraph following the quote seems to allude to Romans 8:29-30. I believe certain clarifications are in order.

Comment: @Lucian. I clarified that in my reply to Nijel J first comment about my question.

Comment: @Lucian, I have edited my question for clarity

Comment: The author of the new creation (Psalm 51:10, 104:30; Isaiah 65:17, 66:22; Romans 6:3-7, 12:2; 2 Corinthians 5:17; Galatians 6:15; Ephesians 4:22-24; Colossians 3:9-10; 2 Peter 3:10-13; Revelation 21:1-2) is the same as the author of the old creation, which, because of sin and evil, stood in need of renewal in the first place. (When one interviews for a job, for instance, one common question is whether they had any previous work experience or prior expertise in that particular domain).

Comment: Can you please  identify who this author of the new and old creation you speak about? Is this author the Almighty God that begot Jesus Christ?

Comment: What might JWs mean by 'begot'?

Comment: @AlexBalilo: If God authored the old creation through His word (Genesis 1 & John 1), the He will also author the new creation through the same word, as opposed to some *other* agency.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a classic example of, "Have you stopped beating your wife?" type.  I reject the implicit assumption that Jesus is a created being; but more on this shortly.

In translating Rev 3:14, versions are divided into several camps depending on how they translate the final phrase, ἡ ἀρχὴ τῆς κτίσεως τοῦ Θεοῦ:

- "the ruler of God's creation." or similar: NIV, NHEB, YLT.
- "the beginning of God's creation" or similar: NLT, ESV, BLB, NASB, KJV, NKJV, NAS1977, ASV.
- "the originator of God's creation" or similar: BSB, CSB, CEV, GNT, ISV, ABPE, God's Word.

The differences all center around the translation of the word, ἀρχὴ (archē) which can mean either start/beginning or chief/ruler.  BDAG defines this word as follows:

1. **the commencement of something as an action, process, or state of being, *beginning***", ie, a point in time at the beginning of a duration, eg, Heb 7:3, John 2:11, Matt 24:8, Mark 1:1, 13:8, etc.
2. **one with whom a process begins, *beginning***, eg, Col 1:18, Rev 1:8, 21:6, 22:13, etc.
3. **the first cause, *beginning***, eg, Rev 3:14.
4. **a point at which two surfaces or line meet, *corner***, eg, Acts 10:11, 11:5.
5. **a basis for further understanding, *beginning***, eg, Heb 5:12
6. **an authority figure who initiates activity or process, ruler, *authority***, eg, Luke 12:11, Titus 3:1, Luke 20:20, etc.
7. **the sphere of one's official activity, *rule, office***, eg, Jude 6.

Note that BDAG suggests that Rev 3:14 has meaning #3 = first cause.  In the case of Christ, this is almost equivalent to #2 and #6.  Thus Rev 3:14 could be translated either, "Ruler of God's creation", or, "Initiator of God's creation", or "beginner of God's creation".  However, this does not mean that Jesus was Himself created.

In Col 1:15, Jesus is described as the first-born (πρωτότοκος) of all creation, meaning (BDAG) that Jesus has a special status as the most important, see also v18, Rom 8:29, Heb 1:6, Rev 1:5, 2:8, etc.

In John 1:1, Jesus is described as existing "in the beginning" with God and thus from all eternity (Ps 106:48, 90:2, 103:17, etc, compared to Micah 5:2).  There is another matter John 1:1-3 - Jesus is also described as creating all things without exception - this means Jesus could not have created Himself.

Comment: @ThomasPearne Your link is to a question that has been down-voted seven times over : something of a record on BH.

Comment: @ThomasPearne Speaking personally, I down-voted the misrepresentation of BDAG.

Comment: @Dottard.John 1:1-3 -"Jesus is also described as creating all things without exception."  John 1:1-3 says.  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 2 The same was in the beginning with God. 3 All things were made through him; and without him [a]was not anything made that hath been made. In these verses, the word was not the creator, why? because creation was fulfilled through him.

Comment: @AlexBalilo - even if that is granted, Jesus cannot be made through Jesus if Jesus does not exist.

Comment: @Dottard, In Revelation 3:14  we have the "faithful and true witness”. He himself said he is “the beginning of the creation by God.”  Add to that his statement in John 3:16 as God's only begotten son and Paul's naming of him as the firstborn of all creation Colossians 1:15. These verses  indicate that Jesus' God and Father begot him and he had a beginning.

Comment: Christ's humanity began. Christ's humanity was created. Col 1:15. In fact He's Preeminent of all creation. As Yahweh, Jesus Christ's Yahweh-hood's without beginning, eternal, uncreated, uncreatable. Heb 7:3; Jn 1:1; 3:16; Prov 8:23-27; Isa 7:14; 9:6. Always a Father, always a Son. He **is** the divine life. As the Word of Yah, He's the very Breath of Yah. Father, Son, and Spirit are One. Deut 6:4; Jn 10:38. As Word of God, He's also God's means of creation; Jn 1:3, 10; Heb 1:2; Rv 3:14; Gen 1:3; Prov 8:22-31; as He and God are One. He is the Origin of creation. (What can JWs mean by "begot"?)

Answer (score 0):

**The First and Last**
Revelation is the revelation of Jesus Christ:

> The revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave him to show to his servants… (1:1) [ESV]

Throughout, Jesus is revealed in various ways, often by a description or a title. At the beginning John experiences such a revelation:

> When I saw him, I fell at his feet as though dead. But he laid his right hand on me, saying, “Fear not, **I am the first and the last**, and **the living one**. **I died, and behold I am alive forevermore**, and **I have the keys of Death and Hades.** (1:17-18)

Jesus is the first and the last: the living one. He died and is alive forevermore, and so forth. After the introduction, Jesus instructs John to record  7 messages to be delivered to 7 churches. Each message begins by Jesus revealing something of Himself:

```
Who           Title
John:         I am the first and the last; the living one. I died and am alive
              forevermore. I have the keys of death and Hades.
Ephesus:      Him who holds the seven stars in His right hand, and walks among the 
              golden lampstands  
Smyrna:       The first and the last, who died and came to life
Pergamus:     Him who has the sharp two-edge sword
Thyatira:     The Son of God, who has eyes like a flame, and whose feet are like
              burnished bronze
Sardis:       Him who has the seven spirits of God and the seven stars
Philadelphia: The Holy One, the True One, who has the key of David, who opens 
              doors no one will shut, and who shuts doors no one opens  
Laodicea:     The words of the Amen, the faithful and true witness,
              the beginning of God's creation
```

Each revelation adds to make a more complete picture, or in the case of the church at Smyrna, reinforces an earlier revelation. No one revelation is by itself complete, and, since all revelations are about Jesus, they all must be in agreement, and in particular, no single revelation can be understood to contradict another given elsewhere.

Therefore, *the beginning of God's creation* (ἡ ἀρχὴ τῆς κτίσεως τοῦ θεοῦ) must be consistent with all Jesus reveals of Himself, and in particular, He is the first and the last.

**The Meaning of "Beginning" - ἀρχή**

> “And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: ‘The words of the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the **beginning** of God’s creation. (3:14)
>
> καὶ τῷ ἀγγέλῳ τῆς ἐν Λαοδικείᾳ ἐκκλησίας γράψον τάδε λέγει ὁ ἀμήν ὁ μάρτυς ὁ πιστὸς καὶ ἀληθινός ἡ **ἀρχὴ** τῆς κτίσεως τοῦ θεοῦ

There are five Biblical uses of the word [ἀρχὴ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G746&t=KJV):

- [a] beginning, origin
- [b] the person or thing that commences, the first person or thing in a series, the leader
- [c] that by which anything begins to be, the origin, the active cause
- [d] the extremity of a thing
- [e] the first place, principality, rule, magistracy

Of these five, "a" and "d" are obviously incompatible with the revelation Jesus is the first and the last. Jesus cannot be the first and last thing created. This is apparent even within Revelation which states there is still a new heaven, a new earth, and a new Jerusalem to come (cf. Revelation 22:1-2). Also, Jesus cannot be the extremities of God's creation.

Jesus could be considered "the person or thing that commences, the first person or thing in a series, the leader" except, He is not the last:

> When all things are subjected to him, then the Son himself will also be subjected to him who put all things in subjection under him, that God may be all in all. (1 Corinthians 15:28)

For the same reason Jesus who is the current ruler, cannot be the last.

Thus, the only meaning of ἀρχὴ which is consistent with the revelation of Jesus Christ is "that by which anything begins to be, the origin, the active cause." In addition, this meaning is consistent with what the New Testament says about Jesus:

> All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made (John 1:3)
>
> He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation. For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him. And he is before all things, and in him all things hold together. (Colossians 1:15-17)
>
> but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created the world. He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high (Hebrews 1:2-3)

It is how the first worship scene in Revelation ends:

> “Worthy are you, our Lord and God, to receive glory and honor and power,
> for you created all things, and by your will they existed and were created.”
> (Revelation 4:11)

Finally, Hebrews specifically identifies the Son as both Creator and One who will recreate:

> <sup>8</sup> But of the Son he says, “Your throne, O God, is forever and ever,
> the scepter of uprightness is the scepter of your kingdom. <sup>9</sup> You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; therefore God, your God, has anointed you with the oil of gladness beyond your companions.” <sup>10</sup> And, “You, Lord, laid the foundation of the earth in the beginning,
> and the heavens are the work of your hands; <sup>11</sup> they will perish, but you remain; they will all wear out like a garment, <sup>12</sup> like a robe you will roll them up, like a garment they will be changed.
> But you are the same, and your years will have no end.” (Hebrews 1)

**The Reward for the Laodiceans**
The reward offered to the Laodiceans serves as added confirmation of how ἀρχή should be understood. Just as each church hears a specific revelation, each hears of a specific reward to the one who overcomes. The Laodiceans are promised to sit with Jesus on His throne:

> The one who conquers, I will grant him to sit with me on my throne, as I also conquered and sat down with my Father on his throne. (3:21)

The Laodicean who overcomes joins His *arche*. This specific revelation and reward are in complete harmony with the letter to the Hebrews which not only describes Jesus as the Creator and the One who recreates, but sits on a throne given to Him by God, His Father. In addition, as do the other revelations, this adds to what is revealed about Jesus. In this case His authority is so encompassing, He is able to share it with those from Laodicea who overcome.

**Conclusion**
As seen above, Revelation 3:14 is in harmony with Colossians 1:15 and John 1:1-3, as well as Hebrews 1:2-3 and 1:8-12. In addition, it is in agreement with the overall message within Revelation about who is the Creator and importantly, man’s proper response to the Creator and the One who recreates:

> And he said with a loud voice,  “Fear God and give him glory, because the hour of his judgment has come, and  worship him who made heaven and earth, the sea and the springs of water.” (14:7)

The issue of proper worship is one of the central themes in Revelation. There are repeated warnings against false worship and repeated scenes of true worship (4:2-11; 5:8-14; 7:9-17; 11:15-18; 14:1-5; 15:2-4; 19:1-8).

The Laodiceans may worship Jesus as the ἀρχή who not only creates and will recreate, He will reward those who overcome by sitting on His throne in the presence of His Father. The image is similar to, but apparently better than the 24 elders. Nevertheless, they serve as examples as they remove their crowns and leave their thrones when they worship.

Comment: The faithful and true witness, Jesus Christ ascribed creation to his Father, the only true God, Revelation 3:14, plainly and unequivocally. Would he still be the faithful and true witness if there are more than one Creator and more than one true God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo He is the true and faithful witness and He is the first and the last. How can He be the first and last [thing] created? He is the first and the last source of creation - see Isaiah 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 in addition to the passages in Revelation.

Comment: How many Creators are there in the bible?

Comment: Christ is God in the Bible, Jn 5:18. There's one God, Jn 1:1, 14

Answer (score 0):

**What does Revelation 3:14 say about Jesus? What kind of witness is the speaker of Revelation 3:14? What does this say about the time of creation?**

The American Standard Version of Revelation 3:14 says,

> And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: These things saith
>   the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of the creation
>   of God.

**What kind of witness "of whom"  is the speaker of Revelation 3:14?**

Jesus himself said that he made his Father’s name manifest.

John 17:6 (KJV)

> 6 "I have manifested thy name unto the men which thou gavest me out of
>   the world: thine they were, and thou gavest them me; and they have
>   kept thy word."

Whilst on trial before the Roman governor Pilate, Jesus said that he came to the world to bear the truth, which was the revelation of God's everlasting purposes for mankind.

John 18:37  (KJV)

> 37 Pilate, therefore, said unto him, Art thou a king then? Jesus
>   answered, Thou sayest that I am a king. To this end was I born, and
>   for this cause came I into the world, that I should bear witness unto
>   the truth. Every one that is of the truth heareth my voice.

One of the reasons Jesus came to the world was "to declare the good news of the kingdom of "God, Jesus said to them.

Luke 4:43  (NET Bible)

> 43 But Jesus said to them, “I must proclaim the good news of the
>   kingdom  of God to the other towns[d] too, for that is what I was
>   sent[e] to do.”

**What does this say about the time of creation?**

**He the firstborn of all creation** as well as the firstborn from the dead?

Proverbs 8:22 (NET Bible)

> 22 The Lord created me as the beginning  of his works,  before his
>   deeds of long ago.

Colossians 1:15  (KJV)

> 15 Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every
>   creature:

Colossians 1:15  (NASB)

> 15 He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all
>   creation.

He the firstborn of all creation as well as **the firstborn from the dead?**

Revelation 1:5 (KJV)

> 5 And from Jesus Christ, who is the faithful witness, and **the first
>   begotten of the dead,** and the prince of the kings of the earth. Unto
>   him that loved us, and washed us from our sins in his own blood,

1 Corinthians 15:23  (KJV)

> 23 But every man in his own order: **Christ the firstfruits;**
>   afterward they that are Christ's at his coming.

Is this verse (Rev. 3:14) harmonious with Colossians 1:15 and John 1:1-3?

Yes, it is harmonious, "the firstborn of all creation" (Col.1:15), and being faithful to  God his Father to the end, has been "appointed heir to all things" ( Heb 1:2).John in his vision(Rev 3:14 states that Jesus is the true witness. Similarly, under inspiration, Paul also draws attention to Jesus as God's spokesman, "Word" or "Logos"(John 1:1) that conveys his message to humans on earth, when he wrote.

Hebrews 1:1-3  (NASB)

God’s Final Word in His Son

> 1 God, after He spoke long ago to the fathers in the prophets in many
>   portions and in many ways, 2 in these last days has spoken to us in
>   His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He
>   made the [c]world. 3 [d]And He is the radiance of His glory and the
>   exact representation of His nature, and [e]upholds all things by the
>   word of His power. When He had made purification of sins, He sat down
>   at the right hand of the Majesty on high,